# How to line up the arrow and structure in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I have the following problems:

1. in the first reaction scheme the arrow is too high and I would like to bring it a little down.
2. in the second reaction scheme the third chemical structure (after the arrow) is a little bit low and I would like to bring it up.
3. in the third structure I would like to connect A to C not to B.

Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass[12pt,doublespacing,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\setatomsep{2em}
\setbondoffset{1pt}
\setdoublesep{3pt}
\setbondstyle{line width=1pt}

\schemestart[0,1.2,thick]
\chemfig{R_3B}
\+
\chemfig{CH_2=CH-C(=[:90]O)-CH_3}
\arrow{%
->[\footnotesize H$_2$O]%
  []%
 }[,2,thick]
 \chemfig{R-CH_2-CH-C(=[:90]O)-CH_3}
\schemestop

\bigskip

\schemestart[0,2,thick]
  \scriptsize\chemfig{[:-30]*6(-=-(-[,1.2]BF_3K)=-=)}
  \arrow{0}[,0]\+{1em,1em ,17pt}
  \scriptsize\chemfig{HO-[:75,,2](-[:115])(-[:150])-(-[:65]OH)(-[:-45])-[:-90]}
 \arrow{%
 ->[\footnotesize SiO$_2$]%
  [\footnotesize H$_2$O]%
  }
  \scriptsize\chemfig{*6(-=-(-[,1.1]B?-[:60,1.1]O-[:10](-[:60])(-[:20])-[:-60](-[:45])(-[:-5])-[:-145]O-[:-195]?)=-=-)}
\schemestop

\bigskip

\scriptsize\chemfig{*6(-=-(-A(-[:90]B*5(-C-*6(-=-=-)=-D=))-[:-30,1.2]OEt)=-=)}

\end{document}
```

[image: reaction scheme]

Comment: the code does not compile without errors

Comment: @cgnieder You are right. Sorry about that. I just fixed that.

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks a lot! As usual, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the alignment issues: you can use anchors as described in section 5 *Anchoring* of part IV *Reaction Schemes* in the `chemfig` manual. Basically this is done using the following syntax:

```
\arrow(.<anchor>--.<anchor>)
```

where `<anchor>` is either the name of the TikZ anchor or the value of a angle. The code below uses

```
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
```

for the first scheme and

```
\arrow(--.-162.5)
```

for the second. You can find details on anchoring both in the `chemfig` manual and of course in the [pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfmanual).

As for the “issue” with the connection of atoms: just draw it the way you want it. Stupid as this sounds it is exactly what I changed in your molecule. The important part is

```
B*5(-C-*6(-=-=-)=-D=)
```

“Rotating” the ring by one bond you get what you need:

```
C*5(-*6(-=-=-)=-D=B-)
```

The code below also fixes the erroneous redefinition of `\printatom` and moves it and the other global settings into the preamble (where they belong, IMHO). I also added indentation to make the code more readable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,doublespacing,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\setatomsep{2em}
\setbondoffset{1pt}
\setdoublesep{3pt}
\setbondstyle{line width=1pt}

\renewcommand\printatom[1]{%
  \fontsize{11pt}{11pt}\selectfont
  \ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\schemestart[0,1.2,thick]
  \chemfig{R_3B}
  \+
  \chemfig{CH_2=CH-C(=[:90]O)-CH_3}
  \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){%
    ->[\footnotesize H$_2$O]%
  }[,2,thick]
  \chemfig{R-CH_2-CH-C(=[:90]O)-CH_3}
\schemestop

\bigskip


\schemestart[0,2,thick]
  \scriptsize
  \chemfig{[:-30]*6(-=-(-[,1.2]BF_3K)=-=)}
  \arrow{0}[,0]\+{1em,1em ,17pt}
  \scriptsize
  \chemfig{HO-[:75,,2](-[:115])(-[:150])-(-[:65]OH)(-[:-45])-[:-90]}
  \arrow(--.-162.5){%
    ->[\footnotesize SiO$_2$]%
      [\footnotesize H$_2$O]%
  }
  \scriptsize
  \chemfig{
    *6(-=-(
      -[,1.1]B?-[:60,1.1]O-[:10](-[:60])(-[:20])
      -[:-60](-[:45])(-[:-5])
      -[:-145]O-[:-195]?
    )=-=-)
  }
\schemestop


\bigskip

\scriptsize
\chemfig{
  *6(-=-(
    -A(-[:90]C*5(-*6(-=-=-)=-D=B-))
    -[:-30,1.2]OEt)
  =-=)
}

\end{document}
```